# issue while pasting content in ckeditor and sending mails

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mobile, ckeditor

when I copy content from my email and paste it on CKEditor Textarea through the mobile phone, it is missing some content like boxes and lines. But copy paste through the web is working fine. Can anyone please help me for finding the solution? [link shows an image of content which I am trying to paste and I am missing that lines and boxes shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmDSg.png)

Comment: Do you mean when you paste through modile phone it doesn't work, but if you paste through your desktop (using a browser) it works? Or do you mean copying from your email mobile app doesn't work, but copying from a web browser it works?

Comment: Do you mean when you paste through a mobile phone it doesn't work, but if you paste through your desktop (using a browser) it works? -- yes

Comment: @IsmaelSarmento yes I mean copying content and pasting it to CKEditor textarea some of the content like boxes and lines are missing in the case of mobile but in a desktop browser, it is working fine can you help me?